# The function doesn't work when called within other functions

Tags: python, function

I am learning Python and trying to write a Python program to read a json file and based on a key in the json I want to get the values. I have not finished the complete code but just some part of it and got stuck in between when using the function. Following is the code:

```py
import json

def read_txt_file(file2):            
        with open(file2,'r') as fc:
           client_data = fc.readlines()
           #print("----------------------")
           #print("client data is", type(client_data))
           #print ("length is", len(client_data))
           for i in range(len(client_data)):
                client_data[i] = client_data[i].lower().strip()
           return client_data

def getting_values_from_dict():
          print("hello")

def read_json_file(file1):
  
        with open(file1, 'r') as fh:
           data = json.load(fh)
           for key,value in sorted(data.items()):
                 return  read_txt_file("client.txt")
                 getting_values_from_dict() 

o=read_json_file("data_usage_20220203.json")
print(o)
```

Here the output I am getting is a list with values from the file `client.txt` which is correct if the function `getting_values_from_dict` is not included. But when I include the function `getting_values_from_dict` which just prints `"Hello"` as shown above, it is not working. This function when called within any of the above function is not printing hello in the terminal. Why so? What is the mistake in this code.

Comment: `getting_values_from_dict` is right after a `return` statement, so it never gets called.

Comment: @JackDeeth thanks. I changed the position of the function and now able to print the string hello

Comment: can we use the returned value as a argument to another function. First function returns `return client_data` , can I use client_data as an argument to getting_values_from_dict() function

Comment: yep, you can do that!

Comment: But when I tried it gave me error `NameError: name 'client_data' is not defined`

Comment: you use the first function as an argument for the second: `getting_values_from_dict(read_txt_file("client.txt"))`